# Thin Metric Space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a complete thin metric space and let $A, B$ be disjoint closed connected subset of $X$ then there is a compact set $K$ such that each neighborhood of $K$ disjoint from $A \cup B$ separates $A$ and $B$.

Can someone explain how I can prove this? I have already read the proofs that used a sequence but I don't really understand how the sequence suddenly becomes Cauchy.

and here is definition of thin space

A uniform space $X$ is said to be thin if for every closed subset $Y$ of $X$ and every $y \in Y$, the uniform quasi-component of $y$ in $Y$ is connected.

here is the prove that i am trying to understand:

To prove this, let $H_{n+1}$ $\subseteq$ $H_n$, $H_n$ seperates $A$ and $B$, and $H_n$ contained in a finite union of balls of diameter < $1/n$. And $K$ = $\cap_n H_n$

It suffice to prove that every open neighbourhood $U$ of $K$ contains some $H_n$ (why?). We reason by contradiction. So assume that for each n there is $x_n$ $\in$ $H_n -U$. We can then easily extract from $\{x_n\}$ a subsequence $\{y_i\}$ such that for each $n$ all but finitely many of the points $y_i$ lie in only one of the finitely many open balls of the fixed cover of $H_n$. It follows then that $\{y_i\}$ is a Cauchy sequence, hence it converges to a point $y$ which
must lie in $K$ and also outside of $U$, a contradiction.

Comment: Googling "thin metric space," I get nothing useful. What do you mean "thin metric space?"

Comment: right forget to define thin space. A uniform space X is said to be thin if for every closed subset Y of X and every y ∈ Y, the uniform quasi component of y in Y is connected

Comment: You should give the proof and explain what precisely you do not understand.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).